# How do you say 'take my dog for an hour long walk'?

Tags: grammar

Going for a walk is "*sanpo ni iku*", right? Would taking my dog for a walk be "*inu no*" or "*ino o sanpo ikimas*"? And then I just add the "*ichi jikan*" in the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

It's the particle を ((w)o) you're looking for to talk about the dog, that you're taking on a walk (marked with the particle に (ni)). To take someone along, you use 連れて行く (tsurete iku).

In the ~ます form, this is one potential answer to your question.

> [一時間]{いちじかん}[犬]{いぬ}を[散歩]{さんぽ}に[連]{つ}れて[行]{い}きます。
>
> ichijikan inu (w)o sanpo ni tsurete ikimasu.